# OpenID connect, OAuth 2.0 and UI functional permissions

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-native, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

We are looking at integrating our apps with Openid connect for our react based apps. We have ui and relevant permissions based on user - menus, navigations etc.

Can anyone point to spec or suggest on how do we handle such permissions in relation to openid connect or oauth. Basically how do we make this permissions available to ui, one approach is dedicated API for ui permissions again authorized by access token.

Another approach is permissions in token itself. Scope is one way of holding info, but it is for delegated access. Hence we are thinking to use multivalued custom attributes for holding roles and permissions in access token. But these permissions can also be huge sometimes and thinking hence if it is good idea to keep permissions in access token.

Any valuable pointers or any design approaches for handling ui permissions list please let know, we highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible option is a custom API endpoint. An access token should hold important identity values such as these:

- User ID
- Roles
- Company ID
- Tenant ID
- Country Code
- Subscription level

These are `claims`, and are populated at runtime for each user, unlike `scopes`, which are fixed at design time.

Access tokens are designed only to be used by APIs, and clients should never read their payload. A good practice can be to return opaque unreadable access tokens to clients, to enforce this.

The actual permissions for a role can be looked up by the API once, then cached. This is preferable to storing large payloads in access tokens.

Finally, permissions for UIs may originate from two data sources: the identity data and your business data. The API can combine a result from both data sources, and transform the result to what the UI needs. Eg which columns are visible, which are read only and so on.

Comment: Thanks much Gary especially for pointing about sources of permissions. Agree, we would use API for getting these permissions authorized using access token. But a quick query, we expose API to return user info again authorized by access token. Would it be advisable to club user info response with these claims or separate dedicated API?

Comment: The cleanest option is to separate them, as you suggest. User info will then be more reusable, eg for screens that only need the user name.